# Sending a SSH packet 32768 bytes or more

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

Part of testing the SSH implementation is verifying the Maximum Packet Length as defined in 6.1 of the RFC 4253. 
Does anyone know how to simulate/test sending SSH packets 32768 bytes or more, and a total packet size of 35000 bytes or more?

Answer (score 0):

[This project](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/documentation/net.html) is easy to test with, provided you can get it to work.

Answer (score -1):

32768 bytes = 32 kilo-bytes 
MTU(Maximum Transmission Unit)는 네트워크 인터페이스에서 세그먼트 없이 보낼수 있는 최대 데이터그램 크기 값입니다. 
만약 데이터가 MTU 값 이상이라면 여러개의 패킷으로 분할이 될 것입니다. 
간단하게 보자면 MTU 는 패킷이 한번에 보낼 수 있는 최대 크기라고 볼 수 있습니다.

The maximum Transmission Unit (MTU) is the maximum datagram size value that a network interface can send without a segment. 
If the data is at least the MTU value, it will be split into multiple packets. 
In a simple view, the MTU is the maximum size a packet can send at a time.

Comment: Please don't post non-English information here.  (Please [edit] your answer to remove it.)